# GCP Pub/Sub filtering on the pull request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I wanted to leverage similar pull request as with the GCP CLI for Pub/Sub subscription:

gcloud pubsub subscriptions pull --filter

I'm looking to leverage the same in Java client libraries.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `--filter` option in `gcloud` is not something that is inherent to Pub/Sub or the service, but rather a utility provided within the `gcloud` command infrastructure itself. The filtering is done entirely on the client side. Also note that this is only affecting the *display* of the list of messages, not what messages are actually returned. If you run `gcloud topic filters`, you can see more details on this functionality:

> Most gcloud commands return a list of resources on success. By default
> they are pretty-printed on the standard output. The
> --format=NAMEATTRIBUTES and --filter=EXPRESSION flags along with projections can be used to format and change the default
> output to a more meaningful result.

Therefore, if you want to perform this action in Java, you will need to write the code to apply the filter upon receiving messages. Based on the [Java asynchronous pull sample](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#asynchronous-pull), you'd need to change the message receiver to something like:

```
  private boolean shouldProcessMessage(PubsubMessage message) {
    // Change to perform whatever filtering you want on messages
    // to determine if they should be processed.
    return true;
  }

  private void processMessage(PubsubMessage message) {
    // Put logic here to handle the message.
  }

  ...
    MessageReceiver receiver =
        (PubsubMessage message, AckReplyConsumer consumer) -> {
          if (shouldProcessMessage(message)) {
            processMessage(message);
          }
          consumer.ack();
        };
```

This is assuming you don't want messages that do not match your filter to be delivered again. If you do want them to be delivered again, you'd want to call `consumer.nack()` on those messages instead of `consumer.ack()`.

If all of the filtering you want to do is on the message attributes, then you can take advantage of [Pub/Sub's built-in filtering](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/filtering). This feature allows you to check for the existence of attributes, check for equality in the value of an attribute, and check for a prefix for the value of the attribute. This type of filter is declared as part of the subscription creation and so you wouldn't have any Java code associated with it unless you are creating your subscriptions programatically. If you use this type of filtering, messages that do not match the filter do not get delivered to your subscriber and therefore your `MessageReceiver` does not need to check to see if it should process such messages; it can assume that the only messages it receives are ones that match the filter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking java client library which is doing pubsub stuff find the docs below. If you need specific thing update your question properly

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#pubsub-client-libraries-java